# send an email using monkey talk automation tool

Tags: facebook, monkeytalk

Is it possible to send an html email report through a monkey talk automation tool. If it is possible please provide any code or url.

Thanks,
Ramakrishna.

Comment: To where do you want to send your mail to? To some User's Facebook account? Please explain a bit what are you asking.

Comment: @AnveshSaxena,send an html report to respective mail ids

Comment: Sorry, but I am still a bit unclear. You want to email report to respective mail ids, and if I am getting it, you need to post this question on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) rather than here cause the question here are supposed a specific problem related to Facebook API and stuff.

Comment: @Anvesh Saxena, thanks for reply but i mentioned flag(monkey talk) for related problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CI (continuous Integration tool) with monkeytalk.

like jenkins+monkeytalk it is bit hard to configure it. but it can be done. use jenkins to automate the process of checkout code from repository and write a shell script to build the project and runtest cases with monkeytalk. after finish tests jenkins will email the reports to the given recipients.

jenkins: http://jenkins-ci.org/

More details...

first of all you need to download and deploy Jenkins. Download[link](http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/war/latest/jenkins.war)

to deploy in terminal

```
$ java -jar jenkins.war
```

open a browser `http://localhost:8080` will take you to Jenkins dash board.

There is link for Jenkins settings on left side menu: from that page you can set an email account , password for Jenkins. and then provide recipient email addresses. so if a build faild Jenkins will email all console errors to the recipents. (try reading  Jenkins documentation if it hard to install)

Then create a new job giving a name and details . add your repository URL and type add user credientials to it. and configure the rest in the end of the page you can give a build command as a shell script or ant file or there are many options. 
then save the job and edit configurations start a build if it not checkout your code from repo and build correctly copy the errors from error console and search in google.

here is a sample code for build a Xcode project to a simulator

```
 echo "Build Start"

/usr/bin/xcodebuild -target FuncTest CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: Leapset Inc." PROVISIONING_PROFILE="xxxxxxxx-1216-4E86-97D5-xxxxxxxxxxxx" OTHER_LDFLAGS="-lxml2 -all_load -lstdc++" DSTROOT="build" VALID_ARCHS="armv7 armv7s i386" -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator6.0 -configuration Release clean build install;

echo "Build End"
```

if you need to open iPhone simulator with the app use

```
# open app in simulator
echo "Start run app in simulator"

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication release-1.081/Leapset/build/Release-iphonesimulator/LeapsetFuncTest.app/FuncTest & disown;

echo "DONE run app in simulator"
```

run tests

```
echo "start run Test jobs"

######### Job 1 #########
echo
echo "TEST: SignInOut.mts"
echo "DISCRIPTION: sign in and out with user credintials"

#java -jar $$ROOTPATH/monkeytalk/LeapsetTest/libs/monkeytalk-runner-1.0.43.jar -agent IOS $ROOTPATH/monkeytalk/LeapsetTest/signinUser.mt
java -jar monkeytalk/LeapsetTest/libs/monkeytalk-runner-1.0.43.jar -agent IOS monkeytalk/LeapsetTest/SignInOut.mts
```

and monkey talk will generate reports. only thing you need to find is some way to attach those html reports to the Jenkins There are so many plugging available for Jenkins.

above commodes are working fine but you need to give the corrects paths to work it. like for above build command 
Note: this command should run in terminal inside the project root directory(where the Xcode project file is)

Good luck
:)

xocdebuild command help

```
xcodebuild 
[-project <projectname>] 
[[-target <targetname>]...|-alltargets] 
[-configuration <configurationname>] 
[-arch <architecture>]... [-sdk [<sdkname>|<sdkpath>]] 
[-showBuildSettings] [<buildsetting>=<value>]... [<buildaction>]...

xcodebuild 
[-project <projectname>] -scheme <schemeName> 
[-configuration <configurationname>] 
[-arch <architecture>]... [-sdk [<sdkname>|<sdkpath>]] 
[-showBuildSettings] [<buildsetting>=<value>]... [<buildaction>]...


xcodebuild 
-workspace <workspacename> -scheme <schemeName> 
[-configuration <configurationname>] 
[-arch <architecture>]... [-sdk [<sdkname>|<sdkpath>]] 
[-showBuildSettings] [<buildsetting>=<value>]... [<buildaction>]...

xcodebuild -version [-sdk [<sdkfullpath>|<sdkname>] [<infoitem>] ]

xcodebuild -list [[-project <projectname>]|[-workspace <workspacename>]]

xcodebuild -showsdks
```

Comment: May i know how to send status email using jenkins. If u have any code please provide me. This is urgent for me.

Comment: Ask if you need any more help. I have done this far with monkeytalk but since it has more limitations to find online help, I went with calabash automated testing.

Comment: Hi @chathura calabash is free tool.

Comment: yea calabash is free: check in here how to install https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios    but remember every automated tool I found is bit painful to setup with jenkins. if you need any help just ask :)

Comment: Thank You so much. Which tool is better for android app testing (robotium or monkeytalk).

Comment: you can check here : http://www.automatedtestinginstitute.com/home/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1413                 for android it is calabash

Comment: Zucchini - A visual iOS testing framework if you need that kind of testing

Comment: Is it free tool? @chathura