# Send status report of test cases using monkey talk

Tags: monkeytalk

How to report errors or test cases status(PASS/FAIL) to developers using monkey talk automation tool for ios/android app testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use monkeytalk with continues integration tool like [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)

Comment: Please i want to know how to use provide some steps or any code.

Comment: You can find the answer here which I posted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675014/send-an-email-using-monkey-talk-automation-tool/16321851?noredirect=1#comment23458989_16321851